# What does 全中制覇 means?

Tags: idioms

I came across this phrase but I can't find in the internet what it means. At first I thought 全中制覇 is an idiom but there was no result when I tried searching for it in the net.

Comment: Where did you come across this?  Can you provide some context?

Comment: I answered the question, but you really should have provided some context.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add the context, I'll always remember to add it from now on. It's a statement said to a martial arts champion. The statement was "全中制覇のウワサはきいてたがここめで強いとは..."

Comment: The statement was said, in the actual competition area after the martial arts champion had won, by the losing competitor. The competition was for 全国大会.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「全中{ぜんちゅう}」 is short for [「[全国]{ぜんこく}[中学校]{ちゅうがっこう}[体育]{たいいく}[大会]{たいかい}」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E4%B8%AD%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1%E4%BD%93%E8%82%B2%E5%A4%A7%E4%BC%9A), which is like all-Japan championship meets for **junior high school** athletes.

Thus, 「全中制覇{ぜんちゅうせいは}」 would mean "winning/becoming a champ at the 全中".

For the advanced learners, the **high school** version of 「全中」 is commonly called [「インターハイ」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E9%AB%98%E7%AD%89%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1%E7%B7%8F%E5%90%88%E4%BD%93%E8%82%B2%E5%A4%A7%E4%BC%9A).

Comment: Thank you. I was so fixed in thinking that it was 4文字熟語, I didn't expect that it was an abbreviated word. ^^